# A satellite in earth orbit, state space representation and the state trajectory

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

**Completely stuck on a homework problem**

The orbital motion of a satellite in earth orbit is given by the following equations:

$\ddot{r}(t)-\dot{\theta}(t)^2 r(t) = \frac{\mu}{r(t)^2}+a_r(t), \mu=\omega_0 ^2 R^3$ (i)

$a_i(t)=r(t)\ddot{\theta}(t)+2\dot{r}(t)\dot{\theta}(t)$ (ii)

where $a_i(t)$ and $a_r(t)$ are the control accelerations, $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ are the radial and transverse components of the position vector and $\mu$ is a constant given for a circular orbit and $\omega_0$ is the angular velocity and $R$ is the radius of the circular orbit and therefore a constant.

What I'm trying to do:

A)

Assuming that the outputs of interest are $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$, obtain a state-space representation for equations (i)-(ii).

B)

Show that $\tilde{r}(t)=R,\tilde{\dot{r}}(t)=0,\tilde{\theta}(t)=\omega_0t+\theta_0,\tilde{\dot{\theta}}(t)=\omega_0$ is the state trajectory associated to null accelerations $\tilde{a}_i(t)=\tilde{a}_r(t)=0$ when the initial condition is $r(0)=R,\dot{r}(0)=0,\theta(0)=\theta_0,\dot{\theta}(0)=\omega_0$ (this state trajectory is the circuar orbit)

C)

Classify the system. If the system is linear, describe it in a compact matrix representation using matrices $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$. Otherwise, linearize it around the state trajectory corresponding to the circular orbit.

**What I've tried to do:**

Laplace transform, but doesn't work due to $L\{\dot{\theta}^2\}=???$
I don't know how to even search for a methodology or how to categorize the problem in terms of differentiation techniques.

Tried to find some algebraic trick to make the problem simpler to be able to perform Laplace transform or some differentiation technique I know, but can't seem to find any.

Any kind of direction/recommended reading to get me moving in the right direction is greatly appreciated!

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You need to first compute the approximate equations called "linearization" for an orbit very close to the circular orbit, more precisely, equations for the difference to the circular orbit. Then you can start with Laplace transforms, if really necessary.

Comment: I have tried Taylor expansion at $ t=0 $, but I don't really know how to perform it unless I have a $ y = f(x) $ type of format which here I don't...

The main thing that separates this problem from my understanding (I think) is the fact that there are differentials of separate functions over time in the same equations. How can I deal with this?

Comment: What is $\omega_n$?

Comment: $ \omega_n $  is the angular velocity, edited correction

Comment: No, it is not a Taylor expansion in $t$ that is required. Set $r=R+h$, $\theta=\theta_0+\phi$ and expand using geometric and binomial series. Then discard all higher-degree terms in $h$ and $\phi$ so that only the linear and constant ones remain. The constant terms should cancel as coordinates of the circular motion.

Comment: There is something wrong in your equations or in your trajectory . Probably, the sign is wrong somewhere.

Comment: And, as far as I understand, $\omega_0$ and $\omega_n$ are the same thing, right?

Comment: I'll try geometric and binomial series!

Yes, I believed to be honest just automatically that they had to be to separate ones where one is initial and the other is the current, but that came from my imagination and is not actually from the task itself. The equations as they are now should be correct though.

Comment: Years ago I had a paper by Dr. Ahmed Kamel that had a nice parameterization of the errors from GEO.  The usual coordinates have singularities there as the line of apsides is not defined at zero inclination and the argument of perigee is not defined when the orbit is circular.  I couldn't find it on a quick search.  Another of his is https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1973CeMec...8..129K